# Repeat a string stored in a variable x number of times

Tags: python, c++, string, printing

I am looking to print a string stored in a variable multiple times. In python I would be able to do this simply by using something like this:

`l1= "*" * width
l2= "*" + (" " * (width-2)) + "*\n"
l3= l2 * ((height-4)/2)`

Where height and width are provided as inputs by the user. Ultimately there are several other lines of code like this that will print a rectangle of *s.

Is there a simple way to do this in C++?

I tried using `l2= std::string((height-4)/2, l1);`, but this causes an error since C++ want a string in place of L2. (l1 is formatted using the `std::string()` function and works properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To go with your code, broken as it is, a sample string for `l1`, a count, and a desired `l2` output would speak *loudly* as an addition to your question.

Comment: @WhozCraig, `l1` and all other variables would be the same as in the python code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` has a constructor that takes a character and a repetition argument, which you can use directly to generate the top and bottom lines, something like:

```
std::string l1 = std::string(width, '*') + "\n";
```

Likewise, the "middle" lines could be generated something like this:

```
std::string l2 = "*" + std::string(width-2, ' ') + "*\n";
```

As for putting the pieces together into a square goes, I'd probably use `std::generate_n` to generate the middle lines, so the code would look something like this:

```
auto l1 = std::string(width, '*') + "\n";
std::cout <<  l1;
std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout), 
    height-2,
    [=] {return "*" + std::string(width - 2, ' ') + "*\n"; });
std::cout << l1;
```

If you really need the result in a string instead of being written to `cout`, you can substitute a `ostringstream` in place of `cout`, and write to it, then use its `str()` member to get the content as an `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple helper function to perform the task if you wanted:

Example:

```
string stringMultiplier(string startString, int multiplier){
    string endString = startString;
    for (int i=1; i<multiplier; i++){
        endString = endString + startString;
    }
    return endString;
}

int main()
{
   cout << stringMultiplier("*",4) << endl; 
   return 0;
}
```